# Weird behavior with jQuery .hover() and $(window).resize()

Tags: jquery, css

#### What I want to do:

I have a navigation bar on my website. Some navigation links have sub-menus associated with them. I want to be able to hover over the navigation links that have sub-menus and have the sub-menu appear.

But, I want the sub-menu to appear differently based on the window size:

- If the window is greater than or equal to 960px wide, my navigation bar is horizontal. I want the sub-menu to appear as a dropdown above the other content on the page.
- If the window is less than 960px wide, my navigation bar is vertical. I want the sub-menu to appear as an accordion, pushing the other navigation links down.

I also want my script to execute when the page is done loading and when I resize the window.

#### My script:

```
function navMenu() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 960) {
    $('.menu-item-has-children').hover(function() {
      $(this).children(".sub-menu").css('display', 'block');
    }, function() {
      $(this).children(".sub-menu").css('display', 'none');
    });
  } else {
    $('.menu-item-has-children').hover(function() {
        $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideToggle(500);
      }, function() {
        $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideUp(500);
    });
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
   navMenu();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
   navMenu();
});
```

#### What happens:

The above script works fine when `$(document).ready()` fires.

The problem lies here: If I resize the window after it has loaded, the script creates multiple `mouseover` and `mouseout` event listeners. One hover over a navigation link causes the sub-menu to bounce up and down repeatedly.

You can see what I mean here: https://codepen.io/ben393/pen/qLrMmX.

#### Some things I've tried (and have not worked so far):

- making `.hover()` a function of `($(window).width() >= 960)`
- making `$(document).ready()` a function of `$(window).resize()`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the issue is that you keep listening to [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) events on every single resize. An easy way to solve this is to unbind the corresponding DOM events every time, with:

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

Note that `hover()` binds both these events in the background. Also note that this will remove *all* custom handlers for these events. You can also store the handler functions into variables and unbind only them if you want to be more specific.

**Demo** (click "Expand Snippet" to test it full-screen):

```js
function navMenu() {
  $('.menu-item-has-children').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
  if ($(window).width() >= 960) {
    $('.menu-item-has-children').hover(function() {
      $(this).children(".sub-menu").css('display', 'block');
    }, function() {
      $(this).children(".sub-menu").css('display', 'none');
    });
  } else {
    $('.menu-item-has-children').hover(function() {
      $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideToggle(500);
    }, function() {
      $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideUp(500);
    });
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  navMenu();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  navMenu();
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
}

ul.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
  ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
  }
  ul.sub-menu {
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="main_header_menu">
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">Main item 1
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>sub item 1</li>
      <li>sub item 2</li>
      <li>sub item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Main item 2</li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">Main item 3
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>sub item 1</li>
      <li>sub item 2</li>
      <li>sub item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks @Jeto!

Answer (score 0):

If you change your resize call to this then it works:

`$(document).resize(function() {
       navMenu();
    });`

Also, you should wrap all your JS inside the `$(document).ready()`